# Is there such a thing as a "body fault" when serving?

Tags: rules, tennis, serve

We know that a foot fault is when your foot touches the baseline before you make contact with the ball. However, what if your feet are planted, and your toss meets or exceeds the baseline, forcing you to lean over the baseline with your body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find anything about this in the [ITF/USTA Rules](https://www.usta.com/content/dam/usta/pdfs/Friend%20at%20Court.pdf), and players very frequently have their body over the baseline. Take a look at this [slo-mo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBkFgS3e4QY) of Roger Federer serving. He (and most other pros) always lean slightly into their serve for the exact reason you specified. It's fair game as far as the rules are concerned.